Change runsettings file for Cross Browser Testing in Playwright Dotnet
Is there any way for us to just change the runsettings file for Cross Browser Testing in Playwright with dotnet (any Test Runner)? I want each test to run in multiple browsers, so that each test is independent of the other and also I accomplish CBT
CBT should work as expected

There are various ways to achieve this

You can do this via command line by passing a different runsettings file every time
  dotnet test --settings:chromium.runsettings
  dotnet test --settings:firefox.runsettings
  dotnet test --settings:webkit.runsettings


You can pass like this too if you want to maintain a single
runsettings file
dotnet test -- Playwright.BrowserName=webkit


You can place a variable in runsettings file, which you can pass from pipeline which would be changed dynamically at runtime
 <browser>#{BROWSER}#</browser>


You can also control stuff if you are initializing your Context on your own in below line by reading the value of browser from pipeline
 If(browser == Chrome) 
 {
    await using var browser = await playwright.Chromium.LaunchAsync();
 }
 else  if (other browser)



Also to save resources you can do 1 thing based on time of the day or a particular day, run your test in a particular browser.
if its Monday then chrome if Tuesday then edge instead of running all browsers all the time
